# Why is the Flash not super smart?

Tags: dc, the-flash

Assuming intelligence is defined by the speed a person can process/calculate information and combined with the fact that the Flash has to think really fast if he wants to control his speed, we can deduce that he has the ability to process the information coming in fast enough to control it.
That being said, if this ability to think quickly exists even when he is *not* running (which there is no reason for it not to), he should be super smart based on the fact that he also has a quicker overall processing rate?

Comment: Define "supersmart". If you asked the Flash to factor a seven digit number down into prime factors, and he used his speed to run to a table, grab a pencil and paper, and manually work out the solution over the course of what would be four hours without his speed, and he comes back with the answer before you notice he left, is he *smart*, or just *hard-working*?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific Flash? Barry for instance, can indeed think very fast even without running, and he's not exactly stupid (CSI and all), while not being on a Brainiac level. On the other hand, Bart for instance features some typical brat stupidity. :)

Comment: My question was asked regarding his intelligence when he is not actively using his super-powers. That question was asked _while_ the Flash was running.

Comment: "Assuming intelligence is defined by the speed a person can process/calculate information" — you might want to ask a psychologist or two about whether that assumption holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being smart is not simply a matter of how fast or how much someone thinks. Someone can think for many hours on end and not come up with the same solution to a problem that someone else might spend mere seconds on, not due to the speed of thought, but from that path their mind takes.

Along with the possibility that a fast thinking individual might simply never begin down the correct path, another element of problem solving beyond time complexity (how long it takes) but also space complexity (how much memory it takes to solve a problem). No matter how long you gave certain individuals, they would never be able to factor very large numbers, not because they don't know how to factor, but because they would run out of working memory in their minds to solve the problem.

Comment: "they would run out of working memory in their minds to solve the problem" — you might be conflating minds and computers there.